# Is there a way to read .wav files as float/int arrays in swift/objective-c and after processing the samples, output it to a speaker or store as pcm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, core-audio

I'm trying to build an iOS app and I need to read a .wav file or microphone input as a float or int array to feed to already existing audio signal processing algorithms in C. Is there an easy way like how wavread is in Matlab?

```
void readAudio() {


NSString * name = @"Test";
NSString * source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"caf"];
const char * cString = [source cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
CFStringRef str = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, cString, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
CFURLRef inputFileURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, str, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

AudioFileID fileID;
OSStatus err = AudioFileOpenURL(inputFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &fileID);
CheckError(err, "AudioFileOpenURL");

ExtAudioFileRef fileRef;
err = ExtAudioFileOpenURL(inputFileURL, &fileRef);
CheckError(err, "ExtAudioFileOpenURL");


AudioStreamBasicDescription clientFormat;
memset(&clientFormat, 0, sizeof(clientFormat));
clientFormat.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
clientFormat.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;
clientFormat.mBitsPerChannel    = 16;
clientFormat.mBytesPerPacket    = clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(SInt16);
clientFormat.mBytesPerFrame     = clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(SInt16);
clientFormat.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
clientFormat.mSampleRate        = 8000;

err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(fileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription), &clientFormat);
CheckError(err, "ExtAudioFileSetProperty");


int numSamples = 64;
UInt32 sizePerPacket = clientFormat.mBytesPerPacket;
UInt32 packetsPerBuffer = numSamples;
UInt32 outputBufferSize = packetsPerBuffer * sizePerPacket;

UInt8 *outputBuffer = (UInt8 *)malloc(sizeof(UInt8 *) * outputBufferSize);

AudioBufferList convertedData;

convertedData.mNumberBuffers = 1;
convertedData.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
convertedData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = outputBufferSize;
convertedData.mBuffers[0].mData = outputBuffer;

UInt32 frameCount = numSamples;
short *samplesAsCArray, *output = (short *)malloc(sizeof(UInt8 *) * numSamples);

while (frameCount > 0) {
    err = ExtAudioFileRead(fileRef, &frameCount, &convertedData);
    if(frameCount > 0) {

        uint64_t startTime = mach_absolute_time()   ;

        AudioBuffer audioBuffer = convertedData.mBuffers[0];
        samplesAsCArray = (short *)audioBuffer.mData;
        FIRFilter(samplesAsCArray, audioBuffer.mDataByteSize/(sizeof(short)), output);


        memcpy([iosAudio tempBuffer].mData, output, audioBuffer.mDataByteSize);


        uint64_t duration = mach_absolute_time() - startTime;

        NSLog(@"%f milliseconds", (float)duration/1e6);

        /*for (int i =0; i< frameCount; i++) {
         printf("%d\n", output[i]);
         }*/

    }
}

free(output);
```

}

I've implemented this much until now. I need to be able to save the edited file as a linear PCM (CAF, as apple works better with that), as text and be able to play the edited audio in real time also.

Comment: ExtAudioFile or AVAssetReader would both work for this.

Comment: Hi @sbooth I am able to import it as an array of shorts. Now that I have processed them, I need them to output to the speaker. I'm not able to do that. Could you help me with a sample code? I'm quite new to objective-c.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have now? It's hard to know what would integrate well.

Comment: I've added the implemented code to the question description.

Comment: Where does all this C code go?

Comment: Hey @Josh this C code is just simple processing of the audio. Some filtering and all that.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I'm having the same problem.